# how to mock datasource in grails for Unit testing

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'm using sql in my domain class finder Method and passing datasource as an argument to sql constructor.
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)

How to mock datasource in unit tests?

any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to interact with a database then your test should be an integration test and not a unit test.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html has a little information, or a general google for "unit vs. integration testing"

If you're not using the `sql` object you are creating, and are just trying to satisfy it's constructor, then passing as map aliased as an the correct class (with appropriate fields and methods) might work. A little example: http://www.groovyexamples.org/2010/05/25/create-a-mock-object-for-an-abstract-class-using-a-map/ **Update: Broken link. Site no longer exists.**